# How to parse an array in an XML VARIANT column in Snowflake?

Tags: arrays, xml-parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a VARIANT column containing XML coming in from Snowpipe. I am able to parse the XML with a wonky combination of XMLGET and GET for most of my fields. However, there is a field that is an array and I'm only able to pull in the first value in the array of  tag values. Each record can have 0 - 100 values in the  tag array, so I need something dynamic enough to cover all of those scenarios. I've spent days trying to work through this and I'm stumped.

Here are some commands to assist in replicating my issue along with a query that has some, but not all, of the values. Please note that this query will be used in dbt to transform data from XML into tabular on a periodic basis with millions of rows coming in, so I also want to bear performance in mind with this parsing... I'm curious if someone has a better method than nested XMLGET commands. I'll add the desired output at the bottom of the post.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this!

```
create temp table if not exists temp_cf_final (RECORD_CONTENT variant);
insert into temp_cf_final
select parse_xml('<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?opentarget version=\"1.1\"?>\n<opentarget xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n<txn id=\"20339559598\" msgIdx=\"76\" msgTot=\"86\" commitTime=\"2023-09-28T10:54:44\" userId=\"349\" oracleTxnId=\"122.17.359225\" />\n<tbl name=\"MAROON_DEV.CF_FINAL\">\n<cmd ops=\"upd\">\n<row id=\"AAIjTAAA7AAHuvTAAZ\">\n<col name=\"DATA\" type=\"varray\" />\n<varray>\n<value>1 street</value>\n<value>    </value>\n<value></value>\n<value>Nashville</value>\n<value>TN</value>\n<value>37211</value>\n<value></value>\n</varray>\n<lkup>\n<col name=\"CF_FINAL_ID\">14773</col>\n</lkup>\n</row>\n</cmd>\n</tbl>\n</opentarget>\n');
insert into temp_cf_final 
select parse_xml('<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?opentarget version=\"1.1\"?>\n<opentarget xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n<txn id=\"20339559598\" msgIdx=\"77\" msgTot=\"86\" commitTime=\"2023-09-28T10:54:44\" userId=\"349\" oracleTxnId=\"122.17.359225\" />\n<tbl name=\"MAROON_DEV.CF_FINAL\">\n<cmd ops=\"upd\">\n<row id=\"AAIjTAAA7AAHuvTAAa\">\n<col name=\"DATA\" type=\"varray\" />\n<varray>\n<value>2486</value>\n</varray>\n<lkup>\n<col name=\"CF_FINAL_ID\">14774</col>\n</lkup>\n</row>\n</cmd>\n</tbl>\n</opentarget>\n');
select record_content
,TO_TIMESTAMP(GET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'txn'),'@commitTime')) as last_commit_time
,GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'@ops')::string as last_operation
,CASE 
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='ins' THEN GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'row'),'col',0),'$')
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='upd' THEN GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'row'),'lkup'),'col',0),'$') 
    END::number AS CF_FINAL_ID
,SUBSTR(GET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'@name'),1,CHARINDEX('.',GET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'@name'))-1)::string AS CUSTOMER_SCHEMA
,GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'row'),'varray'),'$') as DATA_UPD --Works to get me either the single value of "value" or the array of values
,regexp_substr_all(GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'row'),'varray'),'$'),$$"\$":\w+$$,1,1) as DU_values --Works on the array of values, but only pulls the last in the array
,GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'row'),'varray'),'value'),'$')::VARCHAR as DU_first_line --Works great to get the single value, but returns only the first line of an array of values
from temp_cf_final;
```

As you can see from the above...

the DATA_UPD column gives me the singular  value and the array of  values.
The DU_FIRST_LINE takes that a step further, producing the VARCHAR that I want for the singular  value, but only gives me the first line of the array of  values.
The DU_VALUES was my attempt at regex'ing to grab the values from the array, but after literal hours of trying, that isn't going to do it for me.

What I want to see for the  DATA is the array of values string_agg'd and comma-separated (which I can do once I/we/you figure out the array parsing)?

CF_FINAL_ID | DATA

14773 | 1 street,,Nashville,TN,37211,
14774 | 2486

====UPDATE====

I wanted to provide an update on my progress. I received feedback on StackOverflow and from Snowflake Support. Given my business requirements (and with performance concerns noted to my stakeholders), I decided to use a partial flatten and PATH variables to get my data as I need it.

I also found that multiple msg values are passed in sequence for INS (with empty DATA) and UPD (without all keys, but containing DATA) with the same timestamp. I created an operation_order value that would ask for the most recent operation with DEL, then UPD, then INS given priority.

Finally, I added some CTEs to filter down the results and a QUALIFY statement on the operation_order.

```
with cf_final_xml as (select record_metadata,parse_xml(record_content) as record_content from CARELOGIC_DEV.RAW_CL.cf_final where GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(PARSE_XML(RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'cmd'),'@ops') in ('ins','upd','del'))
-- pre-limiting the CF_FINAL records to ins/upd/del reduces the number of rows included in the rest of the query logic
, cf_final_flat as (select * from cf_final_xml,lateral flatten(input => record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'], recursive => false))
-- flattening the "value" node instead of the full table reduces the # of rows in the results, not a full cartesian
select SUBSTR(GET(XMLGET(RECORD_CONTENT,'tbl'),'@name'),1,CHARINDEX('.',GET(XMLGET((RECORD_CONTENT),'tbl'),'@name'))-1)::string AS CUSTOMER_SCHEMA
,RECORD_CONTENT['$'][1]['$']['@ops']::string as last_operation
,TO_TIMESTAMP(RECORD_CONTENT['$'][0]['@commitTime']) AS LAST_COMMIT_TIME
,RECORD_CONTENT['$'][0]['@msgIdx']::NUMBER AS msg_id
,CASE
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='ins' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'][1]['$']::NUMBER
END AS CF_EDIT_ID_INS
,CASE
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='ins' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'][2]['$']::NUMBER
END AS CF_FORM_DTL_ID_INS
,CASE 
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='ins' then 0
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='upd' THEN 1
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='del' THEN 2
END AS OPERATION_ORDER
-- Using OPERATION_ORDER in QUALIFY statement to limit the results to the most recent edit
-- For example, INS and UPD come in with the same LAST_COMMIT_TIME. The OpOrder DESC helps define the last operation
,CASE 
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='ins' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'][0]['$']::NUMBER
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='upd' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'][2]['$']['$']::NUMBER
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='del' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$']['$']['$']::NUMBER
END AS CF_FINAL_ID
, MAX(CF_EDIT_ID_INS) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_SCHEMA,CF_FINAL_ID) AS CF_EDIT_ID
, MAX(CF_FORM_DTL_ID_INS) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_SCHEMA,CF_FINAL_ID) AS CF_FORM_DTL_ID
-- Window functions to attribute the CF_EDIT_ID and CF_FORM_DTL_ID to UPD records
,CASE
    WHEN LAST_OPERATION='upd' THEN record_content['$'][1]['$']['$']['$'][1]::STRING
END AS VAL_ARRAY
,replace(replace(left(right(VAL_ARRAY,length(VAL_ARRAY)-8),length(VAL_ARRAY)-25),'<value>',''),'</value>',',')::STRING as "DATA"
-- ,RECORD_CONTENT
-- ,*
from cf_final_flat
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_SCHEMA,CF_FINAL_ID ORDER BY LAST_COMMIT_TIME,OPERATION_ORDER DESC)=1
-- Only take the most recent operation by time/op across Customers and CF_FINAL_ID values
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_SCHEMA,CF_FINAL_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the last array as a string, and then `regexp_substr_all`:

```sql
select xmlget(record_content, 'tbl') tbl
 , xmlget(tbl, 'cmd') cmd
 , xmlget(cmd, 'row') row1
 , xmlget(row1, 'varray') varray
 , regexp_substr_all(varray::string, '<value>([^<]+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1) arr
from temp_cf_final;
```

[image]